# iPhone midi implementation

Tags: iphone, midi

i want to synchronize my app to an external midi clock. does anyone know of any code base to do this on the iphone?

i dont want to generate midi events i just want to respond to timing information

Comment: Over a physical link or the network?

Comment: the link would have to be over a network

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since iOS v4, an iPhone or iPad can join an OS X CoreMIDI network over Wi-Fi, or connect directly to a MIDI interface using USB.